# ios Shortcuts: get index of selected list item

Tags: shortcuts-app, ios

In an iOS shortcut I can ask the user to select an item from a list, but how do I access the selected index?

I need that in order to get at the selected object in the case where I’ve already converted the objects into more presentable text for the action sheet.

Update:

What I really wanted was to customise the user-facing string representation of an item.

Comment: @fsb It was I who made the edits to the answer without being logged in, in order to make it more clear to future readers which problem the answer solves, and what the intended result of it will be.

Comment: Andreas - just go ahead and post the clearest answer you wish to have or wait for the lock to expire before trying another edit on the locked answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, [this Apple Support site](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/use-list-actions-apd4dcacc115/ios) held the answer.  Use "Set Name" to get the value:

> To set a custom name for an item that an action outputs, such as an
> image in the Get Latest Photos action, **place a Set Name action** in
> between the Get Latest Photos action and the Choose from List action.
> When the shortcut is run, the custom name (rather than the default
> name, such as “IMG_0365”) is applied to the image output from the Get
> Latest Photos action.
>
> If you use the Choose from List action with the Dictionary action, all
> of the keys in the dictionary are displayed when you tap “Add new
> item.” For each key you select, such as Number, Boolean, or Array, the
> corresponding values are passed as output.

Comment: Thanks @fsb for the correction. If the OP needs different wording, perhaps they can post their best answer and select it instead.